# Fortran-like negative indexing in numpy for physics and math equations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, indexing

In contrast to most languages that use zero-based indexing, Fortran allows to specify a particular indexing:

```
! array with 10 elements
double precision arr(-8:1)
arr(-8) = 0  ! 1st element
arr( 0) = 1  ! second to last element
arr( 1) = -1 ! last element
```

The same can be done in the C language by setting pointer to 9th element:

```c
int _arr[10];
int *arr = &_arr[8];
arr[-8] = 0;
arr[ 0] = 1;
arr[ 1] = -1;
```

Is it possible to do the same with numpy arrays? This would be awesome for the implementation of math equations that often feature negative indices, since it would make the code more readable and less error-prone, comparing to standard approach with offsetting indices.

##### One not very satisfying solution

One can overload the `__getitem__` method of `ndarray`, but in my opinion it is (1) cumbersome considering all the ways how numpy array can be indexed; (2) includes a noticeable overhead for the index operator (3) just dangerous to subclass `ndarray`

Comment: What would be a use-case for this kind of indexing? You can already do this with a 10-long array, but the indices won't represent the positions you want: `-8` will be the third element and `0` and `1` will be the first and second elements. You can then pretend as if it starts at the third element and wraps around, and have it behave consistently if you follow this new "convention", but I don't see a good reason why this is necessary in the first place

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, I agree that it is for sure can be already done, so the asked feature can be seen as a syntactic sugar. However, sometimes such feature could make writing code less error-prone and the code itself more readable. The most obvious use-case is sophisticated physical formulas, where it becomes difficult to follow the "convention" of shifted values in the array.

Comment: `numpy` follows the python convention of usIng negative indices to count from the end.  That is very useful.  For example `x[1:]-x[:-1]`.  If that expresion isn't immediately obvious you haven't read enough basic numpy.  Good numpy tries to avoiding indexing individual elements, so you shouldn't have many expressions that need an offset index.

Comment: @hpaulj, Thanks. I am very well aware of vectorization, broadcasting and fancy indexing in `numpy`, it is indeed very helpful in most cases. However, in my case it would be very helpful to have an offset of indices and therefore I am wondering about it.

Comment: Seems like you could declare a 10 element array, then index it with -8, -7, ..., 0, 1, and all of those would be distinct elements. That would probably be the simplest approach.